# Qt multi-line alternative of horizontal layout

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to make a layout where once the first line of it is populated by widgets, it starts adding new ones to the next line. `QGridLayout` sort of looks like what I need, however it has symmetry and I don't want symmetry, cause the widgets are all different sizes. `QVBoxLayout` works perfectly for one line, but making it multi-line would be impossibly hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your goals right, I think using a Flow Layout rather than hacking a QGridLayout would be simpler and probably nicer looking; it just so happens one of the Qt examples is just such a thing (code appears to be BSD licensed, see bottom of page):  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html

Comment: thanks a lot, I think this will help me a lot, however would you know which package for debian I need to get the examples, since I only have qt-creator. qtbase5-examples?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know... This looks helpful though?  http://askubuntu.com/questions/450983/ubuntu-14-04-qtcreator-qt5-examples-missing

And if nothing else, you can cut-and-paste the source files at the bottom of the link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use QGridLayout and still define different sizes for each widget by manipulating the rowspan and colspan parameters in the addWidget call.

For example suppose I have a QTextEdit, a QPushButton and a QLabel that I want to lay out horizontally next to each other. The QTextEdit is four times the width of the QPushButton which is half the width of the QLabel.

I can represent these sizes in a QGridLayout as below:

```
gridlayout->addWidget(textedit, 0 /*row*/, 0 /*col*/, 1 /*rowSpan*/, 4  /*colSpan*/, 0);
glayout_->addWidget(button, , 0, 4, 1, 0);
gridlayout->addWidget(label, 0, 5, 1, 2, 0);
```

Comment: the problem is I am resizing them at runtime as the text inside them grows, will this work in a QGridLayout?

Comment: Unfortunately no. You could also use a single QWidget with a QVBoxLayout and inside this place a number of QWidgets each containing a QHBoxLayout. Within each of these QHBoxLayouts are a number of other QWidgets. You get the idea.

Comment: ok, the QGridLayout may suit my needs, I can just write a function that moves the widgets around/resizes, performance is not critical at this point. I just need to be sure I can do these two things: [1]. add new rows on the bottom of the grid, thus growing it vertically. [2]. add empty spaces that occupy **x** amount of column spaces, so if a new widget is too big, I'll remove it and add it to the next row, but on the previous line I'd like to leave some empty space in the end.

Comment: 1. You can do . 2. You can do by using a QSpacerItem. If this answer is the correct one then mark it as such when you're happy.